# FXML Button activate on enter

Tags: button, user-interface, javafx, fxml, enter

I need to us a .fxml file to build my GUI. I need actually need to make it work without a mouse, just keyboard action....
So, here is the button in fxml:

```
<HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right" 
    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
    <Button text="Login"     
    onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction"/>
</HBox>
```

First of all, I just need this button to do the "handleSubmitButtonAction" event, when the enter key is pressed. (If you have any tips on the secondary objective: getting the arrow keys to navigate through buttons, than by all means fire away ;)   )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`button.setDefaultButton(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#setDefaultButton-boolean-)

Or if you are using FXML:

```
<Button text="Login"     
    defaultButton="true"
    onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction"/>
```

From the javadoc:

> A default Button is the button that receives a keyboard VK_ENTER press, if no other node in the scene consumes it.